# Laplace transform of $t^n$ via induction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

a proposition learnt from 2nd yr DE class says, Let $f$ have Laplca transform $F(s)$. Then
$$ \mathcal{L}(t^n f(t))=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}F(s)$$

Proof.

Write
$$ F(s)=\int^{\infty}_0 f(t)e^{-st}dt $$
Now differentiating under the integral sign gives
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}F(s)&=\frac{d}{ds}\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-st}f(t)dt\\
&=\int^{\infty}_0 f(t)\frac{d}{ds} e^{-st}dt\\
&=-\int^{\infty}_0 t f(t) e^{-st} dt\\
&=-\mathcal{L}(t f(t)).
\end{align}
Thus $\mathcal{L}(t f(t))=-\frac{d}{ds}F(s)$. The general result now follows by induction.

Could anyone show me in detail how the general case follows by induction?

Comment: $t^n=t^{n-1}\cdot t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your last identity,

$$\mathcal{L}(t^{n+1}f(t)) = \mathcal{L}(t\cdot t^{n}f(t))= -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}(t^{n}f(t)).$$

The induction hypothesis replaces this last with

$$=-\frac{d}{ds}  \left( (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{ds^n} F(s) \right) = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{d^{n+1}}{ds^{n+1}} F(s). $$